# ConcurrentHashMap needed with ReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a `Map` which is read by multiple threads but which is (from time to time) cleared and rebuilt by another thread.

I have surrounded all the access to this map with

```
readWriteLock.readLock().lock()
try {
  ... access myMap here...
} finally {
  readWriteLock.readLock().unlock()
}
```

... or the `writeLock()` equivalents, depending on the type of access.

My question is... will the `ReadWriteLock` ensure the updates to `myMap` are visible to the other threads (since they must wait until after the `unlock()` is called by the writing thread?  Or, do I also need to make `myMap` a concurrent map, like `ConcurrentHashMap`?

I will probably do that, just to be safe, but I'd like to understand better.

Comment: what does "rebuilding" mean?

Comment: @michalk a `map.clear()` followed by a bunch of `map.put()` calls.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is generally faster than `HashMap` even in non concurrent use - generally prefer `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider But is everything inside my `try` block guarantee to "happen-before" the `unlock()`?  And, if so, I am right in understanding that that means that readers will see the all the updates, even without using a `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Yup - if you're inside a lock then you guanteed happens before ordering. As long as you take the appropriate lock, `HashMap` is perfectly safe.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that's a very interesting claim that ConcurrentHashMap is faster than regular one even in sequential code. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Your question is back to front. What you don't need here is the *lock.*

Comment: @user207421 Explain please?  I don't want my reading threads to be able to access the map while it is being refreshed.  How can I do that without the lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be fine even without a thread-aware map. The [Javadoc for `ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) explicitly says:

> All ReadWriteLock implementations must guarantee that the memory synchronization effects of writeLock operations (as specified in the Lock interface) also hold with respect to the associated readLock. That is, a thread successfully acquiring the read lock will see all updates made upon previous release of the write lock.

(Of course, by using a reader/writer lock at all you depend on the map supporting concurrent *lookups* from different threads. One could imagine clever data structure that try to save time overall by mutating some internal cached state during a lookup. But the standard collections such as `HashMap` will not do that).